# Insert XML element with attribute into SQL XML column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xml-dml

I have the following XML data stored in `[MyTable].Column1` which is an `XML` type column.

[image]

I want to insert a new element to it:

[image]

I'm using the following SQL, it executed successfully but when I query the same column value again, I do not see my new XML element. Do I miss certain syntax for inserting an element with attributes?

```
UPDATE [MyTable] 
SET Column1.modify('insert <Setting Name="H" Value="0"/> as last into (/SettingValues)[1]')
WHERE ID = 'xxxxx'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code - on the first sight - should work. But you obviously modified it to fit to this forum.

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE(ID VARCHAR(100),Column1 XML)
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES
 ('111'
  ,'<SettingValues>
     <Setting Name="A-name" Value="A-value"/>
   </SettingValues>')
, ('222'
  ,'<SettingValues>
     <Setting Name="A-name" Value="A-value"/>
   </SettingValues>');

UPDATE @MyTable 
SET Column1.modify('insert <Setting Name="H" Value="0"/> as last into (/SettingValues)[1]')
WHERE ID = '222';

SELECT * 
FROM @myTable
```

This works as expected.

```
ID  Column1
111 <SettingValues><Setting Name="A-name" Value="A-value" /></SettingValues>
222 <SettingValues><Setting Name="A-name" Value="A-value" /><Setting Name="H" Value="0" /></SettingValues>
```

After execution you see "1 row affected".

Some ideas:

- The filter is not fullfilled
- The given XML declares namespaces but never uses them... This is a bit odd. Have you reduced the namespaces and your original XML includes a default namespace (or the elements are prefixed somehow)?
- You are checking against the wrong target (other server, other schema, other table...

But: The code above should work...

Comment: Note: Regarding spelling (left things as is although commentary on how to ask a question was removed) - on the line "*The filter is not fullfilled*" should "fullfilled" be "fulfilled"?